# BPF verifier rejects code: "invalid bpf_context access"

Tags: linux, bpf, ebpf

I'm trying to write a simple socket filter eBPF program that can access the socket buffer data.

```c
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>

#define SEC(NAME) __attribute__((section(NAME), used))

SEC("socket_filter")
int myprog(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
        void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
        void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
        struct ethhdr *eth = data;

        if ((void*)eth + sizeof(*eth) > data_end)
                return 0;
        return 1;
}
```

And I'm compiling using clang:

```
clang -I./ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm \
        -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -O2 -target bpf -c test.c  -o test.elf
```

However when I try to load the program I get the following verifier error:

```
invalid bpf_context access off=80 size=4
```

My understanding of this error is that it should be thrown when you try to access context data that hasn't been checked to be within `data_end`, however my code does do that:

Here is the instructions for my program

```
0000000000000000 packet_counter:
   0:       61 12 50 00 00 00 00 00 r2 = *(u32 *)(r1 + 80)
   1:       61 11 4c 00 00 00 00 00 r1 = *(u32 *)(r1 + 76)
   2:       07 01 00 00 0e 00 00 00 r1 += 14
   3:       b7 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 r0 = 1
   4:       3d 12 01 00 00 00 00 00 if r2 >= r1 goto +1 <LBB0_2>
   5:       b7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 r0 = 0
```

which would imply that the error is being caused by reading the pointer to `data_end`? However it only happens if I don't try to check the bounds later.

Comment: Haven't tried running the example yet, but I'm wondering what kernel version you tried it on and whether you made sure the kernel headers match that version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your BPF program is a **“socket filter”**, and that such programs **are not allowed to do direct packet access** (see [`sk_filter_is_valid_access()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/net/core/filter.c#L6451), where we return `false` on trying to read `skb->data` or `skb->data_end` for example). I do not know the specific reason why it is not available, although I suspect this would be a security precaution as socket filter programs may be available to unprivileged users.

Your program loads just fine as a TC classifier, for example (`bpftool prog load foo.o /sys/fs/bpf/foo type classifier` -- By the way thanks for the standalone working reproducer, much appreciated!).

If you want to access data for a socket filter, you can still use the [`bpf_skb_load_bytes()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L1126) (or `bpf_skb_store_bytes()`) helper, which automatically does the check on length. Something like this:

```c
#include <linux/bpf.h>

#define SEC(NAME) __attribute__((section(NAME), used))

static void *(*bpf_skb_load_bytes)(const struct __sk_buff *, __u32,
                                   void *, __u32) =
        (void *) BPF_FUNC_skb_load_bytes;

SEC("socket_filter")
int myprog(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
        __u32 foo;

        if (bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, 0, &foo, sizeof(foo)))
                return 0;
        if (foo == 3)
                return 0;
        return 1;
}
```

Regarding your last comment:

> However it only happens if I don't try to check the bounds later.

I suspect clang compiles out the assignments for `data` and `data_end` if you do not use them in your code, so they are no longer present and no longer a problem for the verifier.