# Network packet counting: Failure to read packet data from a BPF socket filter

Tags: ebpf

I'd like to count incoming network packets and it len in bytes for each TOS value. I created two maps, the first one with 256 entries which contains packet count of each TOS value and the second with packet bytes. So I've written the following eBPF socket filter:

```c
struct bpf_insn prog[]{
  BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_6, BPF_REG_1),

  //we use dgram socket, so packet starts directly from IP header
  // BPF_LD_ABS(BPF_H, offsetof(struct ethhdr, h_proto)), // r0 = header type
  // BPF_JMP_IMM(BPF_JEQ, BPF_REG_0, ETH_P_IP, 2),        // if (r0 == IPv4) skip 2
  // BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_0, 0),                         // r0 = 0
  // BPF_EXIT_INSN(),                                     // return

  //check for IP version, we only interested in v4
  BPF_LD_ABS(BPF_B, 0),                           // R0 = ip->vers: offsetof(struct iphdr, version)
  BPF_ALU64_IMM(BPF_AND, BPF_REG_0, 0xF0),        // r0 = r0 & 0xF0
  BPF_JMP_IMM(BPF_JEQ, BPF_REG_0, 0x40, 2),       // if (r0 == 0x40) goto pc+2
  BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_0, 0),                    // r0 = 0
  BPF_EXIT_INSN(),                                // return

  // load packet TOS value
  BPF_LD_ABS(BPF_B, offsetof(struct iphdr, tos)), // R0 = ip->tos
  BPF_STX_MEM(BPF_W, BPF_REG_10, BPF_REG_0, -4),  // *(u32 *)(fp - 4) = r0
  BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_2, BPF_REG_10),           // r2 = fp
  BPF_ALU64_IMM(BPF_ADD, BPF_REG_2, -4),          // r2 = fp - 4
  //first map with packet counters
  BPF_LD_MAP_FD(BPF_REG_1, map_cnt_fd),           // r1 = map_fd
  BPF_RAW_INSN(BPF_JMP | BPF_CALL, 0, 0, 0,
               BPF_FUNC_map_lookup_elem),         // r0 = map_lookup(r1, r2)
  BPF_JMP_IMM(BPF_JEQ, BPF_REG_0, 0, 2),          // if (r0 == 0) goto pc+2
  BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_1, 1),                    // r1 = 1
  BPF_RAW_INSN(BPF_STX | BPF_XADD | BPF_DW,
               BPF_REG_0, BPF_REG_1, 0, 0),       // xadd r0 += r1

  BPF_LD_ABS(BPF_B, offsetof(struct iphdr, tos)), // R0 = ip->tos
  BPF_STX_MEM(BPF_W, BPF_REG_10, BPF_REG_0, -4),  // *(u32 *)(fp - 4) = r0
  BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_2, BPF_REG_10),
  BPF_ALU64_IMM(BPF_ADD, BPF_REG_2, -4),          // r2 = fp - 4
  //second map with packet bytes
  BPF_LD_MAP_FD(BPF_REG_1, map_bytes_fd),         // r1 = map_fd
  BPF_RAW_INSN(BPF_JMP | BPF_CALL, 0, 0, 0,
               BPF_FUNC_map_lookup_elem),         // r0 = map_lookup(r1, r2)
  BPF_JMP_IMM(BPF_JEQ, BPF_REG_0, 0, 2),          // if (r0 == 0) goto pc+2
  // FIXME big endian
  BPF_LDX_MEM(BPF_H, BPF_REG_1, BPF_REG_6,
              offsetof(struct iphdr, tot_len)),   // r1 = tot_len
  BPF_RAW_INSN(BPF_STX | BPF_XADD | BPF_DW,
               BPF_REG_0, BPF_REG_1, 0, 0),       // xadd r0 += r1

  BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_0, 0),                    // r0 = 0
  BPF_EXIT_INSN(),
};
```

Maps create without errors, socket filter program creates fine too and packet counter part works as it should. But bytes counter is always 0. What is the problem with that code?

I tried to write a simple [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Th5vx4). To compile you just need to include [bpf_insn.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/bpf_insn.h).

Comment: The logics looks correct and I can't find any flagrant mistake. Have you tried calling e.g. `bpf_trace_printk()` to make sure that the length you read from the packet is non-0? Or to check whether the lookup on the second map succeeds? (Unrelated note: I think your second block for reading the TOS and storing it into r2 is not necessary.)

Comment: @Qeole, I tried to change content of last BPF_LDX_MEM and BPF_RAW_INSN entries to the same look as previous, which counts packet - it worked, so lookups on second map should work. I don't use bcc compiler, and create maps and eBPF prog directly from my c++ code. By the way, I agree about reading ToS in the second block, but I commented first 4 lines in the second block and got error. However, commenting only 2 first lines in the second block did work!

Comment: Hmm you mention using `dgram socket`, is it `SOCK_DGRAM`? Pretty sure your context starts at the UDP header instead of the IP header in that case? That could explain why you don't have the expected value for the total length (although I would expect a non-0 UDP port :s). If so, maybe working with raw sockets instead (`SOCK_RAW`) could be a solution? Regarding the ToS parsing, right, sorry, the verifier considers R2 as reset after the call to the map lookup helper so you need to reassign it with the last two lines of the block as you did.

Comment: Well, this is how I create packet socket: `::socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC, htons(ETH_P_IP));` I used unit tests to check at least ToS based packet counter part and it works well. So I assume context should start at the beginning of the IP header.

Comment: Ok, I was supposing `PF_INET`, but with `PF_PACKET` this is correct, you start at the network layer. Not sure what happens then, my recommendation would be to use the eBPF helper `bpf_trace_printk()` to print your packet header and the value you read from it with your `BPF_LDX_MEM()`. Or I can try to have a look if you complete your program so I can compile it. Also do you get the same result with a `BPF_LD_ABS()` instead of the `BPF_LDX_MEM()`? (I would expect so, but just in case.)

Comment: How can I use `BPF_LDX_MEM` to load `tot_len` field into R1?

Comment: @Qeole, I tried to write a simple [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Th5vx4). To compile you just need to include [bpf_insn.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/bpf_insn.h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem: Reading from the Socket Buffer

The context placed in `BPF_REG_1` before the program starts is not a pointer to the beginning of the data. Instead, it is a pointer to a `struct __sk_buff` defined [in the UAPI headers](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h?h=v5.9#n3715) as follows:

```c
struct __sk_buff {
    __u32 len;
    ...
}
```

So when you attempt to read data from your IP header:

```c
  BPF_LDX_MEM(BPF_H, BPF_REG_1, BPF_REG_6, offsetof(struct iphdr, tot_len)),
```

You are in fact reading two bytes at offset 2 from the `struct __sk_buff` (let's call its pointer `skb`). Because your system is in little endian, this corresponds to the most significant bits for `skb->len`, which are 0 unless you have packets bigger than 2^16 bytes (unlikely).

We have two possible solutions here.

#### Solution 1: Use Absolute Load

We can update your program to read the IP length at the correct location. I believe this is not possible with a `BPF_LDX_MEM()`, because socket filters [do not permit direct packet access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61726788/3716552). The workaround would be to use an absolute load instead. Your program would become:

```c
struct bpf_insn prog[]{
  BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_6, BPF_REG_1),

  // ... packet number counter, skipped for brevity

  // Read IP length and store to r7 (preserved during helper calls)
  BPF_LD_ABS(BPF_H,
             offsetof(struct iphdr, tot_len)),    // r0 = tot_len
  BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_7, BPF_REG_0),            // r7 = r0

  // No need to parse ToS a second time here, skipped
  BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_2, BPF_REG_10),
  BPF_ALU64_IMM(BPF_ADD, BPF_REG_2, -4),          // r2 = fp - 4
  //second map with packet bytes
  BPF_LD_MAP_FD(BPF_REG_1, map_bytes_fd),         // r1 = map_fd
  BPF_RAW_INSN(BPF_JMP | BPF_CALL, 0, 0, 0,
               BPF_FUNC_map_lookup_elem),         // r0 = map_lookup(r1, r2)
  BPF_JMP_IMM(BPF_JEQ, BPF_REG_0, 0, 2),          // if (r0 == 0) goto pc+2

  // Now add length to the counter
  BPF_STX_XADD(BPF_DW, BPF_REG_0, BPF_REG_7, 0),  // xadd r0 += r7

  BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_0, 0),                    // r0 = 0
  BPF_EXIT_INSN(),
};
```

#### Solution 2: Just use `skb->len`

The other solution is to get the length from `skb`, since the kernel has already computed it for us. This is just a matter of fixing the offset and length of the load you had, and your `BPF_STX_MEM(), BPF_XADD()` would become:

```c
  BPF_LDX_MEM(BPF_W, BPF_REG_1, BPF_REG_6,
              offsetof(struct __sk_buff, len)),         // r1 = skb->len
  BPF_STX_XADD(BPF_DW, BPF_REG_0, BPF_REG_1, 0),        // xadd r0 += r1
```

Comment: fantastic job! Both solutions work as they should! What I still don't understand is that I use Intel x86 hw which is little endian, however tot_len field of the ip header is stored in network byte order - big endian. But right my now my map with bytes counter stores right values without any transform in the ebpf filter. How come?

Comment: I believe the absolute (or indirect) loads do the `ntohs()` for you. See [BPF documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/filter.html) (grep for `ntohl`).